Understanding piping to a unix domain socket in the background
I have a Debian 12 (bookworm) host where I run three VMs using QEMU / KVM. To simplify VM management, each VM has a QEMU monitor socket. These sockets are /vm/1.sock, /vm/2.sock and /vm/3.sock. Among others, I can use such a socket to gracefully shutdown the respective VM; the command would be something like that:
printf "%s\n" 'system_powerdown' | socat - unix-connect:/vm/1.sock

So far, so good. This works as expected for each of the three VMs / sockets.
Now I have a script that needs to shut down all of these VMs, where no delay must occur if one of the shutdown commands hangs or takes a long time. That means that I have to execute the command line shown above in the background.
The respective part in the original version of that script is:
{ printf "%s\n" 'system_powerdown' | socat - unix-connect:/vm/1.sock; } &
{ printf "%s\n" 'system_powerdown' | socat - unix-connect:/vm/2.sock; } &
{ printf "%s\n" 'system_powerdown' | socat - unix-connect:/vm/3.sock; } &

Apart from the fact that this produces weird output (because the commands are executed asynchronously and their outputs are interleaved), it does not work as intended. It shuts down one of the VMs, but not the other two. During my tests, it was always VM #2 that got shut down, but I believe that this is pure random.
[ Side note: VM #2 takes only 3 seconds or so to actually shut down, while VM #1 and VM #3 take 10 seconds or so; this may be the reason why it's always VM #2 that gets shut down. But let's put that aside for the moment; I wouldn't be able to explain it anyway and still believe that it's random that it's only VM #2 that gets shut down. ]
Then I changed the passage shown above in the following way:
( printf "%s\n" 'system_powerdown' | socat - unix-connect:/vm/1.sock ) &
( printf "%s\n" 'system_powerdown' | socat - unix-connect:/vm/2.sock ) &
( printf "%s\n" 'system_powerdown' | socat - unix-connect:/vm/3.sock ) &

Of course, this version also produces weird output, but otherwise works; it reliably shuts down all of the three VMs.
While I am glad to have a working solution, I would like to understand the matter. After having re-visited the relevant parts of the bash manual, I believe that both versions should shut down all VMs, but this is not the case. Why does the second version work, while the first version doesn't?
Of course, I have read some similar questions on this site and elsewhere that deal with executing commands or pipes in background. From this research I got the impression that both variants should work. Some answers also proposed to move the & into the braces, like that:
(printf "%s\n" 'system_powerdown' | socat - unix-connect:/vm/1.sock &)

But I haven't tried that yet because I first would like to understand the difference between the first and the second version shown above.

Please check if the problematic snippet works with sleep 1 in between the lines. How about sleep 0.001?

Are you sure that the script is executed by bash? Make it explicit with a shebang header!

@KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the proposition, and +1. With sleep 1, the first variant seems to work as well. However, this obviously is not a reliable method because it again does not work with shorter sleep periods, and this makes me believe that there is no guarantee that it always works with 1 s or even 10 s; there must be a better way. Furthermore, I actually don't understand the positive effect of sleep in this case. Would you mind elaborating a bit?

@dest-unreach Thanks for mentioning this pitfall, and +1. However, the shebang (#!/bin/bash) is the first line in all of my scripts :-)

I did not claim it's a solution. Now that we know it works with sleep 1, we may suspect some race condition in the program that uses the sockets. (I do not know QEMU / KVM; is there such a single program for these sockets?) As if when reacting to one command the program was unable to execute/enqueue others, while still consuming them. This would be a bug. My hypothesis was: changing { to ( probably means an additional shell process which may give you just enough delay. I cannot solve the problem, but I believe we've just done non-negligible research.

IMO you should mention this research in the question. My hypothesis, suspicion and conclusion may be omitted (so nobody gets fixated on them), but the sole information that sleep 1 kinda helps should be there.
